# How to handle xml element with both CDATA and regular data using SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml

I'm struggling to understanding how I can deserialize the following response from an RSS feed. I need the text `blah blah blah` etc as well as the embedded image source `http://host/path/to/picture.jpg`.

```
<description>blah blah blah blah br /&gt;
<![CDATA[<img src=http://host/path/to/picture.jpg>]]>&lt;br /&gt;
blah blah blah blah&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
</description>
```

Here's my model class (or rather what I want it to be) - I've shortened it for brevity:

```
public static class Item {

    ...

    @Element(name="description", required=false)
    String descriptionContent;

    String imageLink;
    ...

}
```

From the docs I know I can set `data=true` on the `@Element` attribute but from my reading that works if the entire content of your element is CDATA, not partially.

I'm using doing this on Android using Retrofit and the SimpleXMLConverter but I think that is just by the by.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes without comment. Helped me a lot!

Comment: I got the same problem. Do you have any better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out eventually. Hopefully this will help others in the future.

What was needed was a way to interrupt the deserialization process and run some custom code to extract the data. [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters) allows you to use many different *strategies* for serialization / deserialization. I chose one called the Annotation Strategy where by I annotate my POJO model class with the `@Convert` annotation that points to a converter class.

```
....

@Element(name="description", required=false)
@Convert(DescriptionConverter.class)
Description description;

...
```

And here's what the converter looks like:

```
public class DescriptionConverter implements Converter<RssFeed.Description> {

    @Override
    public RssFeed.Description read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
        final String IMG_SRC_REG_EX = "<img src=([^>]+)>";
        final String HTML_TAG_REG_EX = "</?[^>]+>";

        String nodeText = node.getValue();

        Pattern imageLinkPattern = Pattern.compile(IMG_SRC_REG_EX);
        Matcher matcher = imageLinkPattern.matcher(nodeText);

        String link = null;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            link = matcher.group(1);
        }

        String text = nodeText.replaceFirst(IMG_SRC_REG_EX, "")
                              .replaceAll(HTML_TAG_REG_EX, "");

        return new RssFeed.Description(text, link);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, RssFeed.Description value) throws Exception {
            ...
    }

}
```

You still need to tell Simple to use a different strategy though otherwise it will ignore the annotation. Given that I am using Retrofit and the SimpleXMLConverter here is what my implemenation looks like:

```
private static final Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy())));
```

Comment: your solution is not wrong, but I found more universal solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493919/1537413